# Why are these GlobalSign root certificates different and how to import them from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I'm writing a script that automates adding the latest GlobalSign certificates as found here:

https://support.globalsign.com/ca-certificates/root-certificates/globalsign-root-certificates

I was able to successfully import the following using `certutil -addstore root`:

```
clientauthrootr45.crt
codesigningrootr45.crt
docsignrootr45.crt
iotrootr60.crt
Root-R1.crt
Root-R3.crt
rootr46.crt
root-r6.crt
smimerootr45.crt
timestamprootr45.crt
```

But these certificates failed to import:

```
clientauthroote45.crt
codesigningroote45.crt
docsignroote45.crt
iotroote60.crt
roote46.crt
Root-R5.crt
smimeroote45.crt
```

The error reported was:

```
402.203.0: 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87): ..CertCli Version
Signature does not match Public key: 80090008
313.2389.0: 0x80090008 (-2146893816)
Cannot add a non-root certificate to the root store
313.2398.0: 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13)
313.2668.0: 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13)
313.2830.0: 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13)
CertUtil: -addstore command FAILED: 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13)
CertUtil: The data is invalid.
301.3160.0: 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13)
```

How are these certificates different and can they be imported from the command line?

Comment: Your success list and your fail list is the same ...

Comment: What OS are you importing these certificates on? Do you have any Group Policy configurations affecting ciphers, algorithms, or similar?

Comment: Your lists are very suspect.

Comment: I am importing these on an older Windows XP machine that has expired certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website points out the difference:

> ## RSA Root Certificates
>
> Root-R1.crt (etc)
>
> ## ECC Root Certificates
>
> Root-R5.crt and all the files that look like "*e##.crt"
>
> ...

Windows XP, a 19 year old OS, does not have support for Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC).  That means that the signature in the cert can't be verified, and then a cascade of errors occurs.